# get time as hh:mm:ss in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, time, copy

I have a batch file which is trying to copy a source file to a different directory, but also appending the date and time to the file name. Example command that I have is below.

```
copy /Y c:\apps\BIDW\Sf_Calls.txt      c:\apps\CDW\SF_CDWCalls_%date:~-4,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt
```

However, this command is failing and after some debugging I came to know that time is not parsed correctly. Date gets parsed as 08 for the month, whereas if I run the above command at 7 AM, time is not getting parsed as 07, but only 7 as a result, the destination file name becomes **SF_CDWCalls_20180814_  730** and hence the above copy command is failing with the error message "Invalid Syntax".

Is there a way to get the time as 07:30 using the %time% variable in windows batch file? I see that the time command doesn't support much options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you happen to notice the whitespace between the last `_` and `730` which is caused by the whitespace in the `%time%` variable? You will see it when running `echo %time%` a leading space  `7:30:23,40`

So Conditionally replace the leading space with a `0`. This will only affect single digit `hh`

```
echo %time: =0%
```

So in your script, do this:

```
set "tmptime=%time: =0%"
copy /Y "c:\apps\BIDW\Sf_Calls.txt" "c:\apps\CDW\SF_CDWCalls_%date:~-4,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%tmptime:~0,2%%tmptime:~3,2%.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. However, what happens when I run the copy command at 11:20 AM? Does it become 01120? I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @BalajiPooruli Like I said in my answer, it will only affect single digit `hh` there is no leading space with double digit `hh`, it will still echo `1120`

Comment: @BalajiPooruli: `%time: =0%` replaces spaces with zeros. For `11:20` that means: no spaces, so no replacements.